# Could a fully Saiyan female become a Super Saiyan?

Tags: anime, dragon-ball

Is it possible for a female to become a Super Saiyan, or is it restricted to males? Could a fully Saiyan female (e.g. if Goku was born a girl) become a Super Saiyan? I know that Pan is one quarter Saiyan; perhaps that isn't enough to transform. Could she still change if she gathered enough Ki during battle?

Comment: Female Super Saiyans have appeared in [numerous games](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan), although I know nothing about the canonicity of games in the Dragon Ball universe.

Comment: i asked if they could turn to Super Saiyan, with Black Hair turning Yellow...

Comment: From the page I linked, a female [Super Saiyan](http://images.wikia.com/dragonball/images/7/7d/User1_pic356_1253464937.jpg) in the _Dragon Ball Online_ game.  But like I said, I don't know if the games are canon for the Dragon Ball series, is why I haven't put it in an answer.

Comment: i saw the link. its wierd that they have a female supersaiyan in game but not in series. i was waiting for pan to become a ss.

Comment: Actually _Dragon Ball Online_ is considered canon...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> No female Super Saiyans are ever seen in the manga/anime. However, the Dragon Ball GT Perfect Files implies that Pan has the potential to transform and might have become a type of Super Saiyan never seen before. Female Super Saiyans have since appeared in video games, including Dragon Ball Online and Dragon Ball Heroes. "
>
> Source: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan

So to my understanding it is very possible for a female to become super saiyan in anime/manga, and definitely possible in video games.
Yes, your female Goku would be able to achieve super saiyan state because if Pan is able to become a super saiyan, whether or not it is a new form it would still be considered super saiyan. (:

Comment: I believe this needs updating, as of Dragon Ball Super.

Answer (score 7):

While the extent is not yet know, Dragon Ball Super has introduced the first female Super Saiyan, [Caulifla](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Caulifla). Although she is from Universe 6 (where Saiyans were good, not evil), she is still a Saiyan

> It took Cabba telling her about the Super Saiyan form as well as about being able to achieve greater heights in her strength to make her agree, showing her desire to become stronger.
>
> She also got angry at Cabba for his attempts at provoking her, even to have her obtain the Super Saiyan form. After obtaining the Super Saiyan transformation, Caulifla seemed grateful for Cabba teaching her.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to look it up but as I recall Toriyama said that yes, they can go Super Saiya-jin. The reason he gave for not having any is breast physics. He doesn't know how Super Saiya-jin women's breasts would act/react so instead of dealing with the problem he just didn't make female Saiya-jins.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. There are non-Saiyan female fighters, as well as plenty of regular women, with average or large sized breasts who are animated enough to already have to consider the physics. How would them being a Saiyan add any extra difficulty?

Comment: Well consider Kale, her breasts look male when she goes SSJ. Muscle pump changes how breasts look. SSJ is muscles being pumped up, but it is also possible from a creative point of view that he may have had the idea that SSJ for Saiya-jin women is different, enhancing other aspects greatly rather than just straight power which if was the case would alter how the breasts would look and all like that. - It is simply a matter of an artist/author not caring to think it all the way through cuz there was no need to. The answer is only partial 1 is from the "oh if I do that this has to change.." stage